# Connect to redis Sentinel with Python leads to MasterNotFound Error

Tags: python, redis, redis-sentinel

I have the following setup with Docker-Compose:

```
version: '2'

services:
  redis-sentinel:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-sentinel:6.2
    volumes:
      - redis-sentinel_data:/bitnami
  redis:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis:6.2
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/bitnami
volumes:
  redis-sentinel_data:
    driver: local
  redis_data:
    driver: local
```

The name is my master should be `mymaster`:

```
(base)>docker exec redis_redis-sentinel_1 redis-cli -p 26379 sentinel get-master-addr-by-name mymaster
192.168.80.3
6379
```

I try to connect via Python:

```
from redis.sentinel import Sentinel

sentinel = Sentinel([("localhost", 26379)], socket_timeout=0.5)
r = sentinel.master_for("mymaster")
```

This results in the following error.

```
redis.sentinel.MasterNotFoundError: No master found for 'mymaster'
```

What I tried:

- change localhost to my docker host IP adresss
- checking of `get-master-addr-by-name` with other names works => it does not
- Increased socket_timeout to 5 seconds (https://github.com/redis/redis-py/issues/1125)

So what am I doing  wrong here?

Comment: What does `sentinel.discover_master('mymaster')` return? I would run `monitor` on the redis-cli to see what commands redispy client is sending to the server.

Comment: In my company we actually solved it by adding a service in a container with a script.py entrypoint. It seems to be a docker network issue, but we were not able to solve it